# Sitemap: Expand only current site

Tags: publishing-site

I have a left nav with `StaticDisplayLevels="3"`. I want to expand the navigation of only current sites.

**Expected result:**

```
> Inactive1
> Inactive2
> Current
    > Current's SubSite1
    > Current's SubSite2
> Inactive3
```

**Actual result:**

```
> Inactive1
    > Inactive1's SubSite1
    > Inactive1's SubSite2
> Inactive2
    > Inactive2's SubSite1
> Current
    > Current's SubSite1
    > Current's SubSite2
> Inactive3
    > Inactive3's SubSite1
```

**Control:**

```
<PublishingNavigation:PortalSiteMapDataSource
    ID="rightSiteMap"
    runat="server"
    EnableViewState="false"
    SiteMapProvider="GlobalNavigation"
    StartFromCurrentNode="true"
    StartingNodeOffset="1"
    ShowStartingNode="true"
    TrimNonCurrentTypes="Heading"
/>

<SharePointWebControls:AspMenu
    ID="TopNavigationMenuV5"
    EncodeTitle="false"
    Runat="server"
    EnableViewState="false"
    DataSourceID="rightSiteMap"
    UseSimpleRendering="false"
    UseSeparateCss="false"
    Orientation="Vertical"
    StaticDisplayLevels="3"
    MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0"
    StaticMenuItemStyle-CssClass="right_menu_table"
    CssClass="right_menu_links"
    StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="table_right_menu_active"
    SkipLinkText=""
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not Out-Of-Box behaviour in SharePoint. To achieve this you'll have to use some javascript that will hide the menuitems if the parent does not have the `selected` class.

I use the jQuery library to achieve this (easier way to write javascript)

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Hides all non-toplevel menu items in the quicklaunch
    $("#s4-leftpanel UL.root > LI.static").children("UL").hide();
    // Shows sublevet menu items for selected toplevel in the quicklaunch
    $("#s4-leftpanel UL.root > LI.selected").children("UL").show();
});
```

*The above examples is made by using the default SharePoint 2010 css classes.*

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the jQuery solution. But I don't have LI and UL in the DOM. The menu is created with a complex nested tables. Is there a way to located those TRs?

Comment: @vulcanraven What SharePoint version are you using?

Comment: 2010 Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe you could try to use a different Site Map Provider. There are many providers you can check on internet for more.

So instead of SiteMapProvider="GlobalNavigation" you can use another one.

It is just a thought.